# Lin Master Cannot read slave response

Tags: master-slave, capl, bus, canoe, autosar

I want to simulate a Lin Master request/response on my CANoe Capl.
for this, I'm sending a header from my lin master node to my tested device slave, the slave reveice the header correctly prepare and send the right answer, however on Canoe side the master is not able to receive the response correctly and generate a RcvError ( Unexpected Byte during bus idle phase).
i tried many stuffs : (increasing idle bus timeout to maximum, sending wakeup cyclically) but it still doesn't work.
could you please give me some hint to solve this, here is my code

```
`    on linFrame 5 
     {
       if (this.msgChannel==4)
        {
         setBusContext(Lin_Channel1_context);
         MasterTx5.msgChannel = 1;
         MasterTx5.dlc=0;
         linSetRespCounter(MasterTx5.ID,-1);
         MasterTx5.RTR = 0;
         output(MasterTx5);
         linSetChannelMasterMode(1);
         setTimer(Tx_Master5,1);

        }
      }
  
  
      on timer Tx_Master5
      {
        cancelTimer(Tx_Master5);
        linSetBusIdleTimeout(32767);
        MasterTx5.RTR = 0;
        linTransmitHeader(MasterTx5.id);
      }
`
```